# Matching customer and product ID's to imported data

Tags: import, csv

So, I am setting up a Magento store for a client, who currently has a few thousand products, customers and orders based in a Microsoft Access database and a basic web front end. Now I have access the the Access database, which is a mess, it has no relationships set up, and it integrates with eBay, successfully, to my surprise.

However, the customer has decided to upgrade the system, and I am basing it on Magento, and integrating with ebay via M2E.

I have managed to get all Customer and part data into a CSV, which I have imported into Magento successfully. However, as there was random missing ID's etc in the access database, there are dozens, if not more, customers and parts with a different ID in Magento, than what they had in the old system

I cleared the tables before importing the data, and reset the auto-increment. However, I need them to sync up, so when I import the order data, they actually match up.

Anyone got advice around this? It is too much data to do manually, so as I have literally just added products and customers, is there any way to edit the ID's, or even a better way to import it, and set the ID as a value given from the CSV file?

Appreciate help on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are exactly two options here with regards to the data:

1. Import the data into Magento and assume that any legacy data is unreliable. No amount of wrangling unconstrained external data will guarantee accuracy.
2. Don't import the old data; start fresh from the time of cutover to Magento, and have the old system around to look things up.